# Error creating foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have been searching both SO and Google for this issue, but what i came up with was pretty much what my error message tells me and that's not the problem.

I am using PHPMyAdmin to create relations between tables. I have this table "warehouse_product_history" with a column "from" of type int(11) NULL. I try to create a foreign key to the table "warehouses", and the query that PHPMyAdmin executes when doing so is the following

```
ALTER TABLE  `warehouse_product_history` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES `my_db`.`warehouses` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The type of warehouses->id is int(11) NOT NULL, so that shouldn't be the problem. I've tried to change the datatype of the `from-column to int(11) NOT NULL but with the same result.

I get this error message

```
Error creating foreign key on from (check data types)
```

Comment: What specific error are you receiving? Are you receiving this on an existing populated table? Are both tables `InnoDB`? Have you run `SHOW INNODB STATUS` after trying to create the constraint? Are both columns **identical**?

Comment: Updated the question with the error. The warehouse table is populated. warehouse_product_history isn't. I don't have permissions to show innodb status unfortunately. They are indeed identical.

Comment: Can you share the table schema for both, so that we can try?

Comment: The tables can be found on this link
http://pastebin.com/pTxg8Bzm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your table schema, your columns are not identical. `warehouses.id` is `UNSIGNED NOT NULL` where `warehouse_product_history.from` is signed, `DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The solution was simply to change from sign from signed to unsigned, since i don't need negative ID's.